# Node js TLS Duplex Stream

Tags: node.js, stream, tls1.2

i have the following (simplified) code from a recent ruby project for a readable and writeable stream:

```
class StreamReader
  require 'socket'
  require 'openssl'
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  def initialize
    tcp_client = TCPSocket.new ENV['URL'], ENV['PORT']
    context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
    context.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2
    context.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
    cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
    cert_store.set_default_paths
    context.cert_store = cert_store
    @stream_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new tcp_client, context
    @stream_client.connect
    @requester = StreamRequester.new
  end

  def open_stream
    login = @requester.create_login_request
    @stream_client.puts login
    loop  do
      line = @live_client.gets
      puts line.strip if !line.strip.empty? 
    end
  end
end
```

So I can run:

```
stream = StreamReader.new
stream.open_stream
```

and it prints out the data.

Now I am trying to open the feed with nodejs 6.4.0 but I can't get my head around it.

I think that I need a `net.Socket` and then pass it to a `tls.TLSSocket` which will return a duplex stream. But I can't figure out how to set it up. TLS is built on top of OpenSSL so it should be able to do the same thing.

This my setup so far:

```
var net = require('net');
var tls = require('tls');
var HOST = 'some.url.com';
var PORT = 1234;

var loginRequest = "<Request type='login' user='user' password='pass'></Request>"

//create net.Socket
var socket = new net.Socket();
socket.connect({port: PORT, host: HOST})

var tlsSocket = new tls.TLSSocket(socket,{requestCert:false})
tlsSocket.setEncoding("UTF-8")
//Listen for connect
socket.on("connect",function(){
    console.log("connected to",HOST)
    tlsSocket.write(loginRequest,function (){
        console.log("request sent")
    })
})
tlsSocket.on("error",function(err){
    console.log("ERROR:",err)
})

tlsSocket.on("close",function(){
    console.log("CLOSING")
})

tlsSocket.on("end",function(){
    console.log("END")
})

tlsSocket.on("data",function(data){
    console.log("DATA:",data)
})

tlsSocket.on("readable",function(){
    console.log("SOMETHING TO READ")
    console.log(tlsSocket.read())
})
```

It prints

```
connected to some.url.com
request sent
SOMETHING TO READ
null
END
CLOSING
```

As it says in https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_event_readable `readable` is emitted right before the `end` and data is `null` in this case. The providing company can't assist on that topic, only they know why. I need help to make it work like in the ruby snippet.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the request you're sending is valid? Don't you need some kind of "end of request" marker (CR and/or LF for instance)? Do you receive the "readable" event immediately, or after a delay? Have you tried sending the same request "by hand" using `openssl s_client` for instance?

Comment: @jcaron It's the exact same request like in the ruby snippet. I used xmlbuilder in the ruby snippet but the xmlstring works as well. Just checked it out. The readable event comes after a short delay (1-2 seconds). Sending it manually works.

Comment: `echo -e "<Request type='login' user='user' password='pass'></Request>" | openssl s_client -connect some.url.com:1234 -ign_eof` just starts right away.

Comment: `echo` adds an LF (unless you use `-n`). You may need to do the same in your JS code.

Comment: @jcaron Thanks so much! Adding `\n` to the `loginRequest` works!

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discovered through the discussion in the comments:

- The issue is that the server needs a delimiter to find the end of the request sent and start processing it.
- Adding a `\n` at the end of the request sent resolves the issue.